# How to diagnose intermittent uwsgi errors?

Tags: uwsgi, newrelic

First let me briefly describe our set up before I ask the question proper:

We have a web application server (virtual machine) running a django application. nginx at the front, uwsgi running under that, then a newrelic application wrapper followed by django et al., database is a separate postgresql server located via smartstack (synapse/nerve)

The issue we face is that occasionally (happened once 2 weeks ago, and twice in the last 2 days), one or two of the uwsgi worker processes will trip up and start producing "django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed" on most of their requests.

slightly redacted stack trace (user and application_name):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.8.0.7/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 863, in __call__
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.8.0.7/newrelic/api/function_trace.py", line 90, in literal_wrapper
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.8.0.7/newrelic/api/web_transaction.py", line 752, in __call__
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 194, in __call__
    signals.request_started.send(sender=self.__class__)
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 185, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 91, in close_old_connections
    conn.abort()
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 374, in abort
    self.rollback()
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 177, in rollback
    self._rollback()
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 141, in _rollback
    return self.connection.rollback()
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 141, in _rollback
    return self.connection.rollback()
  File "/home/user/webapps/application_name/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.8.0.7/newrelic/hooks/database_dbapi2.py", line 82, in rollback
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

The stack trace never gets in to our application, it only touches new relic and django. Once a worker trips, it doesn't recover and all further requests result in 500's in the uwsgi logs and 502's on the front side. I assume database connectivity is fine because the sibling workers continue to function normally, and restarting uwsgi instantly fixes the problem.

My question is how one would go about diagnosing this issue to pinpoint the root cause, I have checked everything I know how to check (memory, cpu, logs, database connectivity) and some things I don't fully understand but am trying to read up on (file descriptors mainly).

For now I updated new relic (stack trace is older version) as it's the only thing I felt I could do.

I would appreciate any feedback, many google searches have proved fruitless.

replies may be slightly delayed, my timezone says it's time to sleep. Also, apologies if this should be on serverfault or something, I just figured it's closer to an application debug issue than a server config issue.

Comment: You can safely ignore the New Relic instrumentation stack frames in the traceback -- those simply indicate that New Relic was monitoring that transaction, not that New Relic was causing the error.

It looks like the problem is being caused by the database closing the connection, which could have a myriad of causes (database being restarted, network issues, etc.)

Comment: Okay, that makes some sense, but I still don't know why it's happening and why to only certain workers and why there's no problem once workers are killed and respawned. I also considered this situation and added connection logging on the postgresql server for next time, turns out that's not there by default :(

Comment: if your workers automatically reconnect there is nothing you should worry about, as already lauradiane told you there are literally tons of reason for that error (they could depend on postgresql, or particular queries causing problems). If your workers donot reconnect (and this is a known issue with django+psycopg2 with at least 3 tickets opened about it), you can instruct uWSGI to automatically recycle workers on exceptions as described in trick 7 here: http://www.slideshare.net/webdebs/djangoday-lt-20120420

Comment: @roberto these tickets after googling them have given me a lot of leads and the uwsgi tricks might temporarily suppress the issue (though I'll still be looking for an actual fix rather than treating a symptom) Although the question "how would I diagnose this" isn't answered, I'd be more than happy to mark you as an answer if nobody else answers anything in the next few days (and you switch your comment to an answer), Thank you!

Comment: you were both quite right. We have HAProxy on this machine for database load balancing (to 1 postgres machine, it's a company infrastructure thing and soon to scale). While postgres isn't closing the connection itself, HAProxy does that for us and somehow causes the connection to be in an invalid state due to pyscopg2 bugs --> we have to close the connection on the django side ourselves. Which is fine, but IF we ever get any requets that take too long our uwsgi workers will die. Don't know how we will choose to tackle that yet but I have enough to go on. Thanks!

Comment: Try restarting PostgreSQL. It was the magic solution for me. After restarting PostgreSQL all the errors disappeared.